# ctrl alt key problem

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, bug-reporting

I have a Problem With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> Key in Ubuntu ( 16.04 , 16.10 , 17.04 tested ) .

When i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> the System do Something unwanted ( for now it minimize the window ) .

I face with this problem both in my desktop and my laptop.

When i try the new installation of Ubuntu it's fine But after some days it sucks again :-(

Maybe installing some packages cause this ... i have no idea for this problem ...

sometimes restarting work sometimes not , sometimes log Out and log in work ... sometimes change the action :| (also i tried to close Compiz and it worked sometimes for me but every time i spend Huge minutes to get rid of this )

Comment: Try a different keyboard. Clean your keyboard (don't use soap & water)

Comment: @waltinator i mentioned that i used different systems and its the same:)

Comment: Same here.  This is an old bug!